# Factory and singleton patterns: undefined reference

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, singleton, factory

I have tried to understand what's going on in my situation from other questions in this site, but I haven't really found a good answer. I tried most of the suggestions I found but still get the same error.

I am trying to implement a factory based on a singleton and the CRTP. So I have a Singleton class, define in Singleton.h:

```
template<class T>
class Singleton
{
public:
  static T &instance()
  {
    static T one;
    return one;
  }

  Singleton(const Singleton &) = delete;
  Singleton(Singleton &&) = delete;
  Singleton &operator=(const Singleton &) = delete;
protected:
    Singleton() = default;
};
```

I also have a Factory class, defined and implemented in Factory.h. The factory creates objects of a hierarchy whose base class is, for the purposes of this question, `Object`. These objects all have a constructor accepting a `double`.

```
class Factory : public Singleton<Factory>
{
    friend class Singleton<Factory>; // to access constructor
public:
    using createFunction = Object *(*)(double);

    void registerObject(const std::string &, createFunction);
    Object *createObject(const std::string &, double) const;
private:
    Factory() = default;
    std::map<std::string, createFunction> theCreatorFunctions;
};

void Factory::registerObject(
    const std::string &ObjectId,
    createFunction creatorFunction)
{
    theCreatorFunctions.insert(
        std::pair<std::string, createFunction>(
            ObjectId, creatorFunction));    
}

Object *Factory::createObject(
    const std::string &ObjectId, double a) const
{
    auto it = theCreatorFunctions.find(ObjectId);
    if (it == theCreatorFunctions.end())
    {
        std::cout << ObjectId << " is an unknown object."
                  << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    return (it->second)(a);
}
```

Finally, I have a "helper" class that registers new types of Objects into the factory. Each time a new inherited object is created, say `ObjectDerived`, I add (in the .cpp file where `ObjectDerived` is implemented):

`FactoryHelper<ObjectDerived> registerObjectDerived("ObjectDerived");`

This creates an object of type `FactoryHelper<ObjectDerived>`, whose constructor handles the registration in the factory. `FactoryHelper` is defined (and implemented) in `FactoryHelper.h`:

```
template<class T>
class FactoryHelper
{
public:
    FactoryHelper(const std::string &);
    static Object *create(double);
};

template<class T>
FactoryHelper<T>::FactoryHelper(const std::string &ObjectId)
{
    Factory &theFactory = Factory::instance(); // the one and only!
    // if it doesn't exist at this point, it is created.
    theFactory.registerObject(ObjectId, FactoryHelper<T>::create);
}

template<class T>
Object *FactoryHelper<T>::create(double a)
{
    return new T(a);
}
```

So the problem that I have is that I get a bunch of undefined references to `Factory::instance()`, basically one for each type of object in the hierarchy.

If I put all in the same main.cpp file it works, but this is not a solution I'd like.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. To make your code complete, I added a very simple Object class and main() function, all in one file. Granted, I did not create a hierarchy of classes inheriting from Object. Could you create a MCVE by providing the minimal base Object and derived classes and main function to show your problem, and include the compiler errors?

Comment: @jwimberley I just did the same actually, and had to edit my question, since apparently I did something wrong before: putting all in the same cpp file does not generate an error. But this is not an ideal solution, really.

Comment: In that case it seems like it might be a compiling/linking problem rather than a problem with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no compilation error when all your code is in one file, and you don't use any extern global objects that could cause issues with multiple files, I suspect that you have a problem in your compilation/linking script.

For the record, I can confirm that you have no intrinsic problem in the code. Adding a hierarchy

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object(double _value) : value(_value) {}
    virtual double getVal() { return value; }
private:
    double value;
};

class SpecialObject : public Object
{
public:
    SpecialObject(double _value) : Object(_value) {}
    virtual double getVal() { double val = Object::getVal(); return val*val; }
};
```

the simple main routine

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FactoryHelper<Object> baseMaker("Object");
    FactoryHelper<SpecialObject> derivedMaker("SpecialObject");
    Factory& factory = Factory::instance();

    Object* a1 = factory.createObject("Object",4);
    std::cout << a1->getVal() << std::endl;
    Object* b1 = factory.createObject("SpecialObject",4);
    std::cout << b1->getVal() << std::endl;
    Object* c1 = factory.createObject("NonexistentObject",4);

    return 0;
}
```

has the expected output:

```
4
16
NonexistentObject is an unknown object.
```

By the way, a matter of opinion: Your `FactoryHelper<T>` class does not achieve much, essentially acting as a shortcut for registering an object with the default allocator/constructor. At some point, making new classes stops actually saving much code. If you can use C++11, it's not much more difficult to write

```
factory.registerObject("SpecialObject", [] (double a) -> Object* { return new SpecialObject(a); });
```

If you wanted, you could add shortcut method to `Factory` itself:

```
// definition
template <class T>
void registerObject(const std::string &);

// implementation
template<class T>
void Factory::registerObject(const std::string &ObjectId)
{
    registerObject(ObjectId, [] (double a) -> Object* { return new T(a); });
};
```

With this, the `FactoryHelper` class can be eliminated, and the equivalent `main` routine to before is

```
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Factory& factory = Factory::instance();
    factory.registerObject<Object>("Object");
    factory.registerObject<SpecialObject>("SpecialObject");

    Object* a1 = factory.createObject("Object",4);
    std::cout << a1->getVal() << std::endl;
    Object* b1 = factory.createObject("SpecialObject",4);
    std::cout << b1->getVal() << std::endl;
    Object* c1 = factory.createObject("NonexistentObject",4);

    return 0;

}
```

Again, if you are able to use C++11, you can always make `createObject` wrap the raw `Object*` pointer in a smart pointer (as you may well know, and maybe you have good reasons already for not doing this).

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what was going on. It seems to work now with separate files as well, after a make clean. Thanks for the tip for eliminating FactoryHelper as well :)

Comment: I am actually having new troubles.. I can register objects with your approach in the main routine, but ideally I want to do it on each new class that I introduce (in its own .cpp). The lines `Factory& factory = Factory::instance();
    factory.registerObject<Object>("Object");` give me an "unknown type name" error for `factory` (in the second line) if this is done on one of those files. No errors at all if done on main().

Comment: Hm, could you post the complete error? Was your strategy before to have these classes inherit from FactoryHelper, e.g. `WidgetObject : public FactoryHelper<WidgetObject>`?

Comment: I defined your Object hierarchy in Object.h and put the lines `Factory& factory = Factory::instance();
    factory.registerObject<Object>("Object");
    factory.registerObject<SpecialObject>("SpecialObject");` in Object.cpp

Comment: The error: `src/Object.cpp:5:1: error: unknown type name 'factory'; did you mean 'Factory'?

factory.registerObject<SpecialObject>("SpecialObject");

^~~~~~~

Factory
include/Factory.h:19:7: note: 'Factory' declared here

class Factory : public Singleton<Factory>
      ^
src/Object.cpp:5:8: error: cannot use dot operator on a type
factory.registerObject<SpecialObject>("SpecialObject");
       ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [obj/Object.o] Error 1`

Comment: You need to be more specific about where you put this code in Object.cpp. Is it a part of the class constructor, or is it just a line unto itself? I would expect the latter case to fail (using either my Factory suggestion or FactoryHelper) because `Factory::registerObject<T>(std::string&)` is a function call and must exist in main or some function called by main, for many reasons. Putting this in the constructor *might* work

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, it was a line unto itself, so it makes sense that it fails. I think that's the main reason why I used the FactoryHelper, because the registration could be called within the constructor (this was a suggestion I followed without thinking much about what I was doing). I don't want to put it in Object's constructor, since I want the registration to happen even if no Objects exist.